# NRZI bitstuffing Sharp EL-5500III (PC-1403)?

Tags: audio, audio-recording, digital-audio

I have an old audio cassette tape of digital data I converted to .wav and am hacking to recover the original data. I demodulated the 4K/2K FSK modulation with minimodem. I initially thought it might be NRZI and I get stuck with insufficient understanding of the NRZI bit-stuffing algorithm. Short-cut: does anybody know of sox-like or minimodem-like program that does NRZI decoding through Linux pipes?

Many references explain that bits are stuffed into NRZI data streams after 5 consecutive bits of one polarity.  But to be precise, I haven't found a clarification.  Does this mean:

1. a bit stuff happens after 5 bits, or
2. a bit stuff happens in order to prevent a run of 6 bits?

By example, if the original data is ...11111001... does it get transmitted as is, or does a bit stuff occur to send the data ...111110001... ?  If the bit-stuff is only to cause a transition after 5 bits, then the stuff is not necessary.  But the docs say "after 5 bits" which would create unnecessary stuffs if the original data had inherent runs of exactly 5 bits.

Here's the specific bit stream I have demodulated, but not de-encoded. It's from a Sharp EL5500III calculator/computer.  Any help demodulating it would be appreciated!

`root@kali:~# minimodem --rx -R 44100 --mark 4000 --space 2000 --binary-raw 26 -f monoshort8008.wav 500 CARRIER 500 @ 4000.0 Hz 11111111111111111111111111 11111111111111111111111111 11111111111111111110111010 00001111100000100000111110 00001000001111100000100000 11111000001000001111100000 10000011111000001000001111 10000010000011111010101011 11111110100010001011111000 00100000110000010010111000 00101100110101110111111000 10101000110000010101111000 00100000110100010001011000 00100101110101110101011000 10101001110110010101111000 10101000110101110000011011 00100000110101110100011001 00101011110110010100011000 00101011110000010000011010 00100111110000010110011010 11101011110001010100111000 00101011110000010000011001 00100001110000010110011010 11101001110001010100111000 00101011110000010000011011 00100100110000010110011000 11100010110001010100011000 00101011110111110111111011 11101111110000110111011110 NOCARRIER ndata=29 confidence=150.653 ampl=0.126 bps=500.04 (0.0% fast)`

Notice the sets of 5 bits near the beginning. Notice also the periodicity of 13 bytes, visible as vertical column runs of 1 or 0 through all the data.

Comment: You failed to mentioned what concrete kind of encoding you are dealing with. There's probably a wide range of NRZI variants out there, with different bit length according to whatever other factors influence that, and it's impossible to guess which one you are dealing with. As for software: gnuradio is very flexible, and if you need FSK demodulation with additional stages, whatever they are, gnuradio is the first thing I'd try.

Comment: I'm using "NRZI" in the way Wikipedia defines it.  I'm specifically referencing the bit-stuffing rule "after 5 bytes", which is an NRZI standard.  I hope that someone knows the the protocol with the precision needed to answer the question.  I will go look at gnuradio more, but I'm hoping for a command line "pipe-savvy" utility rather than a big software suite.

Comment: The problem is that bit-stuffing in NRZI is **not** a standard. The bit stuffing is needed to keep the receiver synchronized, because if the level of the signal doesn't change over a longer time, clock skew between sender and receiver can happen. How much clock skew can be tolerated depends on the hardware, transmission speed, etc. E.g. in USB, after 6 consecutive 1 **bits**, an additional seventh **bit** is inserted (on other words, runs of 7 consecutive 1-bits are not allowed). As you still haven't said what protocol you use, I have no idea if the threshold for yours is 5 or 6 bits.

Comment: Dirtkt,  All references I've found on NRZI (easy one see Wikipedia) include bit stuffing, so I think it's a standard because it's used to preserve clock sync.  I've read "after 5" and "after6".  My question is to clarify is it "after 5" or "to prevent 6" (or after 6/prevent 7).  If the data itself has an inbound transition on the next bit, the stuffing might not be necessary.   The protocol I am asking about IS NRZI. I did not say what the encoding the recording is using because that's what I'm trying to determine!  I want to make sure I'm decoding NRZI correctly before I use it on the data.

Comment: Dirkt,  I modified the original post to include the bit stream.

Answer (score 0):

No, NRZI **is not a protocol**. No, NRZI **does not define any particular number of bits for bit stuffing**.

NRZI doesn't even imply that you use bit stuffing; given another way to synchronize clocks, you don't need it. **Protocols** that use NRZI define bit stuffing length.

USB uses NRZI, and defines that after 6 bits, you bit-stuff the 7th.

SDLC and HDLC use NRZI, and define that after 5 bits, you bit-stuff the 6th.

That's why the wikipedia paragraph reads:

> ... while HDLC and USB use bit stuffing: they insert an additional 0 bit (forcing a transition) after 5 or 6 (respectively) consecutive 1 bits.

The "5 bits" is for SDLC/HDLC, the "6 bits" is for USB.

So in USB, the sequences `0111110` and `01111110` are allowed. The sequence `011111110` is forbidden (as a data item), and must be changed to an allowed sequence by bit stuffing.

In SDLC/HDLC, the sequence `0111110` is allowed. The sequences `01111110` and `011111110` are forbidden, and must be changed to an allowed sequence by bit stuffing.

This means you have different allowed and forbidden sequences in two protocols that both use NRZI. So **NRZI doesn't define a particular number of bits for bit stuffing**.

So you **need** to refer to the actual protocol that you use, because without naming this protocol, it can be any number of bits.

> I demodulated the 4K/2K FSK modulation

means it's not USB.

> I have an old audio cassette tape of digital data

also means it's likely not an IBM mainframe protocol like SDLC or HDLC, though it could be a derived protocol like X.25.

So if you want help in figuring out whatever that is, you **need** to include more information. If you are reluctant to provide that, then we cannot help you.

If you have no idea what protocol it is, you'll still have some information where you obtained the audio cassette etc., that will help to narrow it down.

If you even don't have that, then you still can do statistical analysis: See how often sequences of different length happen, and draw your conclusions or hypothesis from that.

Comment: Dirkt, Thank you.  Now I get what you're saying about NRZI isn't a protocol but layered on top of SDLC or HDLC (or whatever). I'm trying to determine if it's NRZI and I'm trying to determine the underlying bit algorithm. I don't know either because I'm trying to determine both.  It's a program save from a Sharp EL5500III calculator/computer. Instead of going to tape, I recorded it directly to a wav file. Uggh.. how do I leave a blank line in comment?  I edited the original post to include the raw bit stream.